# Url rewrite in web.config http to https AND non-www to www AND no trailing slash

Tags: ssl, url-rewriting, web-config

Web.config URL rewrite is giving me headaches :-)
I'm trying to setup rewrite rules following these conditions:

1. It should produce only one single redirect
2. Ignore resources
3. remove default.aspx
4. remove trailing slash
5. lowercase (not querystring) when not using custom file extentions
6. force www
7. force https

All this is working great, except when the original url allready has WWW in it. If the url has WWW then is will follow all rules but won't redirect to HTTPS.

Any help would be greatly appreceated!

Here's what I have so far ([inspired by this great article](https://moz.com/blog/what-every-seo-should-know-about-iis#chaining)):

```
  <rules>


    <rule name="WhiteList - resources" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^resources/" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="SEO - remove default.aspx" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*?)/?default\.aspx$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="_{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="SEO - Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.+)/$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="_{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="SEO - ToLower" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.pngx|\.jpgx|\.gifx|\.bmpx|\.orcx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="_{ToLower:{R:1}}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="ADD WWW IF NOT PRESENT" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(_*)(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.testssl\.orca-bree\.be$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.testssl.orca-bree.be/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(_+)(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but it should work:

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*"></match>
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.be$"></add>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"></add>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mydomain.be/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"></action>
</rule>
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.mydomain.be/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

What I've changed:

- Actions of your rules. Now they contain full domain name with `www` and `https`
- Added `MatchAny` to your conditions in the first rule

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it but I'm still getting an error when using  http : //  www . mydomain . be. (no ssl, www) Without the www it works just fine.

Comment: Can you try to replace `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"></add>` with `
<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^http:"></add>`   Sometimes depends on network infrastructure `{HTTPS}` condition might not work

Comment: thanks for the help but I've updated my original question to match all of my requirements. Have been experimenting some more, but really got stuck on this one.